# Append input type property not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table structure dynamic add row option. It makes a new row when I click add but problem is **$("[name*=vehicle_type]").change(function ()** it's not work for append input field

Only work for this

```
<select name="vehicle_type[]" class="form-control company" id="company" required>
              <option value="type">Type</option>
</select>
```

But not works for this

```
$('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select name="vehicle_type[]" class="form-control company" id="company" style="width: 140px;" required><option value=""> Type</option>'+val_all_types+'</select></td></tr>');  
  });
```

Here is jquery code

```
$("[name*=vehicle_type]").change(function () {
      //  alert('ok');
        var $type = $(this); 
        var $row = $type.closest("tr"); 
        var $cat = $("[name*=vehicle_category]", $row); 
        var $subcat = $("[name*=vehicle_sub_category]", $row);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getCat',
            type: "get",
            data: { type: $type.val() },
            success: function(data) {
                $cat.empty();
                $subcat.empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                    $cat.append($('<option>', {
                        value: d.id,
                        text : d.V_Category
                    }));
                });
            }
        });    
    });
```

Comment: Give this a quick read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace
`$("[name*=vehicle_type]").change(function () {`
to
`$(document).on("change", "[name*=vehicle_type]" , function() {`

Comment: Thanks a lot. it's working. Can you please describe why that not works?

Comment: It's because you need to delegate the event to an element that is static on the page. Rather than `document` you should use nearest element instead.

Comment: Your code is generated dynamically. To bind the `change` event to all existing and future elements, you need to use the jQuery on() method

Comment: If you have time can you please provide me your answer on **$("[name*=vehicle_type]").change(function () {**

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Rather than document you should use nearest element instead. – EternalHour